# How can I use a delegate to check if NSUserDefaults value changed?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

I have a string that is assigned to a NSUserDefaults object but I need to have *code* run when the value is changed. How can I use a delegate to check a NSUserDefaults objects value?

Comment: Looking at the other question and now that I know more about Objective-C, this question actually isn't a duplicate. The other question is asking how to respond to NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification and get the value that had changed. I however had no idea that there was an NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you need to use `KVO (Key Value Observing)` to check for change in the `NSUserDefaults`

Register for KVO with the following code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"YourValue to observer" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

Remove the observer in '-viewDidDisappear'

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"YourValue to observer"];
```

Finally implement the following method to receive KVO notifications,

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"Output : %@ changed property %@ to value %@", object, keyPath, change);
}
```

Comment: viewDidUnload is no longer called in iOS 6. You should remove the observer in viewDidDisappear or dealloc.

Comment: Although the question was marked as a duplicate, your answer is greatly appreciated for how simply you put it.